# Is there a limit to the amount of input streams created

Tags: android, io, inputstream

Very simple question but could not find an answer anywhere.
Is there a limit to the amount of input streams that can be created at any one time.

Example. Lets say I want to upload 100 things at once. Is it possible (on Android) to open up those 100 input streams and simultaneously read form them, without memory issues?

Or is it better to just keep a small amount of inputstreams open at any one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a system limit to the number of file descriptors that can be open by a process.  Check out http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html and OPEN_MAX in particular.  You can also drop to your Android Terminal Emulator and do a `ulimit -n` to give you a per process file limit.  Without knowing what you're trying to do exactly, I would say yes, try and keep the number of input streams to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks, What I am trying to do is upload files in the background, as a backup thing. They are async from the thread that started it, so there can be multiple uploads happening at once, and the input streams are closed in a callback